# Distributed application with client side stuff?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, dapp-development

I would like to write a smart contract which allow users to publish forecasts and then vote which forecast was the best. Adding a forecast should be done manually by user. But I would like to automate voting process.

In theory it should be easy. There is a need to download some data from the internet, compare with published forecasts and choose the best one. But is this approach supported by ethereum? I don't see possibility of writing "client side" part. I'm not sure how it should be done "by the book".

Comment: Have you looked at the concept of Oracle? For instance oraclize.it will let you fetch data from the internet.

Comment: Yes, I have seen it. But to be honest I would prefer to get all needed information from users. In this case I don't need to depend on third party services. Also instead of paying oraclize I would prefer to pay users for the data.

Comment: Your idea sounds more like a betting market then.

Comment: You could use of for betting but then by looking for users who are winners most of the time you can find best forecasts.

Comment: You can use anything that is need of your project along with smart contract. But your other layer should not affect the features of smart contract.